# Does the PS3 version of Tekken 5 not have ending videos?

Tags: version-differences, tekken-5

I'm thinking of buying this game on the PSN Store, but I heard that the PS3 version doesn't have ending videos. Is that true?

Comment: Are you talking about Tekken 5 or Tekken 5: Dark Ressurrection?

They are similar (same game), but DR is an updated and more mainstream version

Comment: Dark Resurrection.

Comment: @Oak I wasn't sure if that part of the title was necessary. It didn't fit the tag length so I just removed it. If it should be "tekken-5-dr", go ahead and fix it.

Comment: @Vemonus I was about to edit it when I noticed that Tekken tags are barely explored. The thing is, Tekken 5 barely has any differences (I believe it's just with Jinpachi), kind of like Skyrim and Skyrim SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what's seen on [This Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN5xesDwdjA), after beating the game you are shown the credits, and then have to download the epilogue (which should be unlocked). This is opposed to what happens in the Playstation Portable, where the Epilogue is shown after beating the Final Stage